# Sending Data from Javascript to Asp net Core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

i need send data from js to core.

in back i have this model

```
public class AddEmployeeVm {
     public EmployeeVm Employee {get; set;}
     publi List<PrivilegesVm> Privileges {get;set;}
}
```

**EmployeeVm**

```
public string FirstName {get;set;}
public string LastName {get;set;}
public IFormFile Image {get;set;}
```

**List Of Privileges**

```
public string UserId {get;set;}
public string PrivilegeId {get;set;}
public string PrivilegeName {get;set;}
public bool Create {get;set;}
public bool Read {get;set;}
public bool Update {get;set;}
public bool Delete {get;set;}
```

so, in my api i need to receive complex data with files an fields

i cant come up with data append, because can't receive list of privileges,
i can't go with json solution becouse can't send files...

so please help me, what javascript code will be a valid?

Comment: You just need to post the form with all the relevant information and the shape it to match your classes on the server.  Don't try to shape it before you post it.

Comment: i don't have a form, i'm posting with ajax

Comment: Check out the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File); you can send files easily via POST that way. Apart from that, this question is far too broad, try to help yourself and come back when you have a specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

The below is the `JavaScript` code for posting values using **AJAX**.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        data: { parameter1: Value1, parameter2: Value2},
        url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // Process the received data.
        }
    });
```

In the below `Controller`, the parameter Names **must match** the ones that are being posted using AJAX.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ActionName(string parameter1, string parameter2)
{

}
```

Comment: OP wants to send files via POST too. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` does not support files.